# Compound boolean expressions in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic, boolean, predicate, logical-operators

In Prolog, how do you implement compound logical predicates like (A and B) or (C and D)?

This may seem like a simple question but many approachable online tutorials are not detailed enough on boolean expressions.  I assume you can't just write:

```
test(A, B, C, D) :- cond(A), cond(B); cond(C), cond(D).
```

so how would you do it?

Comment: If you'd tried running that piece of code, you'd have found that it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As noted by others, your original example

```
test(A, B, C, D) :- cond(A), cond(B); cond(C), cond(D).
```

is perfectly valid (assuming the parse is as you intended it). Didn't you try it?

**A Primer**

*Logical AND*

```
foo :- a , b .
```

*Logical OR*

```
foo :- a ; b .
```

*Combined*

```
foo :- a , b ; c , d .
```

The above parses as:

```
foo :- ( a , b ) ; ( c , d ) .
```

Use parentheses to indicate a different desired binding:

```
foo :- a , ( b ; c ) , d .
```

Even better, eschew the `;` OR operator and break alternatives up into separate clauses. Sequence is much easier for people to comprehend than branching tree structures. Breaking alternation up into multiple clauses simplifies testing/debugging and improves comprehension. Therefore, prefer

```
foo :- a , b .
foo :- c , d .
```

over

```
foo :- a , b ; c , d .
```

and prefer

```
foo :- a , bar , d .

bar :- b .
bar :- c .
```

over

```
foo :- a , ( b ; c ) , d .
```

Possibly most importantly, breaking things up into multiple clauses like this makes later maintenance easier. With a structure like:

```
foo :- a , b ; c , d .
```

what do you do when you add another case? What about when it expands to 50 alternatives?

Each additional alternative increases the number of code paths through the clause, thus making testing and comprehension more difficult. To get complete code coverage in testing, a lot of alternative paths must be individually tested.

With the equivalent structure

```
foo :- a , b .
foo :- c , d .
```

Adding alternatives is simply a matter of adding additional clause or clauses, each of which can be tested in isolation.

A professional programmer writes first for the people who will, several years down the line, need to comprehend, change and fix that code (**hint:** that person might be yourself).

Answer (score 1):

A simple alternative for conjunctions is to use substatements. For disjunctions, use multiple lines. Your example:

```
test(A, B, C, D) :- test1(A, B).
test(A, B, C, D) :- test2(C, D).
test1(A, B) :- A, B.
test2(C, D) :- C, D.
```

What about (A or B) and (C or D)?

```
other(A, B, C, D) :- other1(A, B), other2(C, D).
other1(A, B) :- A.
other1(A, B) :- B.
other2(C, D) :- C.
other2(C, D) :- D.
```

Note that this is only mentioned as an alternative to joel76's answer.

Answer (score 0):

test(A, B, C, D) :- (cond(A), cond(B)); (cond(C), cond(D)).

Comment: @Mog: No need for the parentheses, but if mixing ANDs and ORs it helps to clarify operator precendence and binding. For a lot of people, an expression like `a AND b OR c AND d` is unclear as to whether it binds as `(a AND b) OR (c AND d)` or does it bind as `a AND (b OR c) and d`? Further, which was intended? This is a rather common source of bugs in many programming languages, so it helps to explicitly indicate the desired binding &mdash; one of the few places, IMHO, where extraneous parentheses actually do anything to improve the signal/noise ratio.

Comment: sure sure, but it's not acceptable as an answer in my opinion, it should at least precise that it only explicits things and that it is equivalent to OP's code. That's why I downvoted.